# Error when trying to install java11 with brew

Tags: homebrew, java-11

I'm trying to install java11 on Mac with

```
brew cask install java11
```

and I got an error:

```
  Error: Cask java11 exists in multiple taps:
  homebrew/cask-versions/java11
  caskroom/versions/java11
```

Can you please help to fix this error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following commands resolve the issue with conflicting casks and then install `java11`:

```
brew untap homebrew/cask-versions
brew untap caskroom/versions
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
brew cask install java11
```

Comment: Thank you, @slavov! This worked perfectly for me. I was going nuts with this.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
brew install java11
```

I also had to do this command so that it was in my path:

```
sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk@11/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.jdk
```